# Opening flutter app by clicking on push notification shows blank splash screen without icon

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter app with a splash screen with an icon image.  I am testing the app on a real Android device.  The app makes use of Firebase.  When I open the app, I see the splash screen with the icon as expected.

However, when the app is closed and a push notification is received, clicking the push notification opens the app with a blank splash screen. The icon image in the splash screen does not show up.  Does anyone know what could be the problem:

Here is some code that I have:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
  RemoteMessage remoteMessage,
) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Maybe your app is launched with a "hot start"? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#how

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DhafinRayhan.  How would I know if the app is running in "hot start"?  Because I see the splash screen's background but without the image.

Comment: When I receive a push notification, the app is closed.  It is not running and it is not in the background.  So I suppose when I click on the push notification, the app should be in cold start.  Ins't this true?